# Why can't I use var when declaring sub name spaces?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, module-pattern

Why does the following work

```
var NameSpace = NameSpace || {}; 
NameSpace.Foo = 2;
```

But this does not?

```
var NameSpace = NameSpace || {}; 
var NameSpace.Foo = 2;
```

Any insight into the inner workings of the variable deceleration in regards to namespaces would be appreciated.

Comment: NameSpace.Foo is not a variable, it's an object property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript does not have namespaces. Your first line of code is declaring a variable whose name is `Namespace`, and whose value is an object:

```
var NameSpace = NameSpace || {};
```

Then you create a *property* `Foo` on the object, and assign a value to it:

```
NameSpace.Foo = 2;
```

Bottom line: variables and object properties are different things (among other differences, variables have scope, while properties don't). The [`var` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) is only for declaring variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
var foo = foo;
```

works because ECMAscript will decouple this line in away like

```
var foo;
foo = foo;
```

under the hood. This concept is commonly called *hoisting*.

Your second snippet can't work, since we are assigning an *object property*. The `var` keyword always implies, that we want to create a *variable*, a *symbol* so to speak, within the current *Execution Context*.

What you could do of course, is

```
var Foo = NameSpace.Foo = 2;
```

This would

- create the variable `Foo` in the current context
- assign the object property `Foo` on the `NameSpace` object
- assign both the value of `2`

Answer (score 0):

`var` is reserved for declaring new variables, not modifying existing ones.

Additionally `.` is an invalid character for a variable name.